# Hybris Solr Indexation

Tags: solr, indexing, sap-commerce-cloud

I'm new to hybris and I'm having problems with the usage of SOLR.

I have a catalog with prices and I want to use webservices because I have a custom UI and I want to use hybris as backend.

What I do is simply map the electronicsSolr index to my site and start a full indexation. Afterwards, when I invoke the webservice ../rest/v1/{webSiteName/catalogs/{catalogName}/{catalogVersion/?options=CATEGORIES, PRODUCTS - I see everything...

but when I call rest/v1/{webSiteName/products?query:price-asc:category:{myCategory} some of the products are missing. can you give me na idea where do I make a mistake? Probably I have to set up something in the electornicsIndex that I'm using but I dont know what...

Answer (score 0):

It may not be missing the products, its may be due to pagination results, can you please check the number of products you are getting. Some times you will get 20 products which is like default number of products for a page in pagination results. For getting other set of results try sending page number as 2, 3....